# Calculate sum and count of even and odd numbers

Tags: c#, beginner

Started learning C# second time. I have written a console program to calculate sum and count of even and odd numbers. Provided code :

```
using System;

namespace Studying_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            uint evenNumbersCount = 0;
            uint oddNumbersCount = 0;
            int sum = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number in the range to find out it odd or even. The program won't count numbers you entered in the sum");
            int numberOne = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number");
            int numberTwo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (numberTwo < numberOne)
            {
                int a = numberTwo;
                numberTwo = numberOne;
                numberOne = a;
            }

            while(numberOne < numberTwo - 1)
            {
                numberOne++;

                int result = numberOne % 2;
                sum += numberOne;

                switch (result)
                {
                    case 0:
                        evenNumbersCount++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        oddNumbersCount++;
                        break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Sum - " + sum + " | Even - " + evenNumbersCount + " | Odd - " + oddNumbersCount);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

> Input  : 2, 5
> Output : "Sum - 7 | Even - 1 | Odd - 1
> 2 and 5 aren't counted

Is this code good? Can I improve it or optimize?

P.S. Sorry for my english and if I did something off-topic. Let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: Have you tested the results? The first number will not be counted as you increment it before summing. The second one will be excluded as well. Shouldn't the range be inclusive?

Comment: Yes, I did, it works as it supposed. I know how to make it counted if I need it.

Comment: Just a small thing. Your main routine prompts the user with the string, "Enter the first number in the range to find out it odd or even..." That isn't bad and because I can see your code I know what are allowable values. I'd like to suggest you provide the range, something like, "Enter an integer value from -2147483648 to 2147483647". Or restrict it for the user to something like "-10000 to 10000".  Its likely most people would think of integer values, rather than trying to enter something like 3.14159. But, just to prompt them is good.

Comment: Are you interested in simplifications like just counting odd numbers, and then calculating even count as  `evens = n - odds` where `n` is the length of the range?  Obviously the whole thing here could be reduced to closed-form so you don't need to loop. (Odd and even are both about `n/2`, with adjustments based on the first and last numbers.  And Gauss's `n * (n+1)/2` for the sum of 1..n can be adapted for a range, and also done without possible overflow if necessary, like clang does when optimizing a `sum+=i` loop like this.  But I'm guessing that these are placeholders for real work.)

Comment: Adding odd numbers can be reduced to `sum += i & 1` if you care to do it that way, taking advantage of the fact that C# (like most languages) uses binary integers.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher, thank you, I have read this question on the link. Does it mean that I can just add self-answer with updated code If I want to share it with others? Furthermore, I can just ask new question with updated code, reffering to this one, If I want to know more (Of course it won't be dublicate question)

Comment: A self-answer should be in the form of a code-review and shouldn't just place the updated code and shouldn't repeat what other answerer already posted. A follow-up question would be better if you want the updated code to be reviewed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The naming could be better. `numberOne`, `numberTwo` and `result` does not tell anything about what these numbers represent. Better `rangeStartExclusive` and `rangeEndExclusive`. The `...Exclusive` makes it clear that the bounds will not be counted.

I also would use a for-loop. This is the standard way of looping a number range. It also allows us to easily define a loop variable. The problem of incrementing `numberOne` is that it makes it a range bound and a running variable at the same time. This double role decreases readability.

Instead of an `int` result, I would use a Boolean telling its meaning.

```cs
for (int n = rangeStartExclusive + 1; n < rangeEndExclusive; n++) {
    bool isEven = n % 2 == 0;
    if (isEven) {
        evenNumbersCount++;
    } else {
        oddNumbersCount++;
    }
    sum += n;
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep your original implementation and instead rename `result` to `remainder`.

It is okay to give our number a non-descriptive name like `i` or `n`, often used in math to denote a whole number. `i` is often used for indexes.

To keep the declaration and use of `isEven` close together, I have moved `sum += n` to the end of the loop. It looks strange if you first calculate `result`, then calculate an unrelated sum and only then use `result`.

Why use `uint` for the count of even and odd numbers? This count will always be smaller than the range bounds given as `int`. The maximum `uint` is about the double of the maximum `int`.

However, the sum could exceed the maximum `int`. The sum of all whole numbers starting at 1 and up to `n` is `n * (n + 1) / 2`. When starting counting at 1, this limits the maximum number at 65,535. Therefore, it would make sense to use `long` for the sum.

Comment: Is there some advantages to use `if` instead of `switch`? In my opinion, `switch` is more readeable here. Or is it so because `switch` requires more performance?

Comment: The main reason was to be able to give the variable `result` the name `isEven`. You could also name it `remainder` instead and keep the original code.

Comment: In traditional / pseudo-code 1-letter var names, `n` is most often used for loop upper bounds, with `i`, `j`, or `k` as a counter.  It's not totally weird to use `n` as the loop counter / induction variable, but it's more common and idiomatic IMO for `n` to be loop invariant.

Comment: Another advantage of `n % 2 == 0` is that this way works for negative odd numbers. @JediMan's switch would only count positive odd numbers, because `-5 % 2 == -1` not +1.  Probably a good idea to mention that correctness reason along with stylistic reasons in this answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes, The reason I have chosen `n` is that while it is used as loop variable, this is not its primary intent. We want to perform a mathematical analysis (even/odd) on this number. For this purpose `n` is good. Maybe a more consequent approach would be to use `i` as loop variable and to pass it over to a method doing the math part as a parameter named `n`.

Answer (score 8):

You already have answers, but lets add one more for learning purpose. This is another way of doing the same thing. Not a better way, just an alternative one to showcase some C# features. If you feel a bit overwhelm, it is normal. You don't have to know everything and nobody expect you to do. If you have any questions, feel free to post them in comment. I will be more than happy to answer them :)

We will use [tuple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), [tuple's deconstruction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct), [linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/), [interpolated string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), [lookup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-5.0), [lambda operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) and more. Take the time to read the docs above, there are a lot of things going on below. Here we go:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static (int, int) SumCount(IEnumerable<int> source) => (source.Sum(), source.Count());

    public static (int, int, int) SumCount2(IEnumerable<int> source, Func<int, bool> predicate)
    {
        var results = source.ToLookup(predicate);
        var (evenSum, evenCount) = SumCount(results[true]);
        var (oddSum, oddCount) = SumCount(results[false]);
        return (evenSum + oddSum, evenCount, oddCount);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> RangeWithoutStart(int start, int end) => Enumerable.Range(start + 1, end - start - 1);

    public static void Main()
    {
        var start = 2;
        var end = 6;
        var range = RangeWithoutStart(start, end);
        var (sum, evenCount, oddCount) = SumCount2(range, x => x % 2 == 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"Sum - { sum } | Even - { evenCount } | Odd - {oddCount}");
    }
}
```

[Try it Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gQcoSI)

The current implementation of `SumCount` will loop twice into `source`, we can reduce to one by using [`Aggregate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0):

```csharp
public static (int, int) SumCount(IEnumerable<int> source) => source.Aggregate((0, 0), (a, b) => (a.Item1 + b, a.Item2 + 1));
```

Learning concept:

- Beside `Main()`, everything is [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).
- We don't [mutate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) anything.
- `SumCount2` is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

These concepts are keys in [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) but here it shows the beauty of a multi-paradigm language like C#.

Comment: I think this answer is too advanced for the beginner level of the OP.

Comment: @RickDavin I think it is nice to discover new way of doing stuff. I learnt linq by looking at example. I decided to post because I dont think that I am the only person who love to learn by example. I will add a caveat though.

Comment: Thank you very much! This code is a set of symbols and words for me, so it definetily on another level for now) Currently, I'm studying with a course on youtube, but after the end, I promise to have a deal with it.

Comment: @JediMan You will have all the time needed. Have fun learning. C# is a great language.

Comment: @RickDavin Learning new things is hard. It gets easier and more relevant when the thing solves an active problem you have (under the same vein as "even food you don't like tastes better when hungrier"). OP is in a _prime_ position to understand and learn, as they are acutely aware of the problem domain since they just tried to solve it themselves. Code reviews can entail improved implementations when it adds something (and is not just an arbitrary rewrite), as is the case here.

Answer (score 6):

You should try your program whith different values.
When asked for the first number, enter "abcdef". Hit enter, and see what happens.

In such a case, when you can't be sure that the string to parse is ok, use int.TryParse(...).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know this program will throw exception if I enter "abcdef". The question is whether I can improve code somewhere to gain more performance or make better for understanding. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Will it be better to use `try catch` instead of `TryParse`? If I use `TryParse()`, it will return zero and my calculating will be wrong. Isn't it good to use `try catch` to catch exception and do a warning then?

Comment: @JediMan Good question. Try it with `TryParse` and you'll find it actually returns `false`! `TryParse` returns `true` if it is able to parse, and `false` otherwise. That means you can use it in an `if` block and end the program or display an error if the user entered bad input.

Comment: @Nate Barbettini, understood and dealed with `TryParse()`, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's good.
I think loops in this case are not needed.
The following is based on the famous:

```
1 = 1^2
1+3 = 2^2
1+3+5 = 3^2
...
```

Included the loop so you see how it waits.
It is not well tested and it can be improved:

```
namespace odd
{
    public record Result
    (
        long oddCount,
        long eavenCount,
        long sum
    );
    class Program
    {
        static Result mathPreliminaries(long start, long finish){
            // remove one from finish and add one to start
            // to make them exclusive
            // you can also hack other parts to get desired output
            finish -= 1;
            start += 1;
            // total numbers in this range 
            // eg start = 2, finish = 5 => [2, 3, 4, 5] => count = 5 -2 + 1 = 4
            long totalNumCount = finish - start +1;
            // the following is the same as {finish//2 + finish%2} just(i think) more efficient with bit hack
            // you can see by {1+ 3+ 5 = 3 ^2}  that the total count of odds is 3, same as:
            // 5//2 = 2 + 5%2 , that is 3
            long finishOddCount = (finish >> 1) + (finish & 1);
            // we do the same for the starting number
            // from previous example would be starting at number 2: 
            // 2//2 = 1 + 2%2 = 1, so you see there is only one odd {1 = 1^2}
            long startOddCount = (start >> 1) +(start & 1);
            // now you apply the square part to get the sum 
            // {1+ 3+ 5 = 3 ^2 = 9}
            long oddFinishSum = finishOddCount * finishOddCount;
            // {1 = 1^2 =  1}
            long oddStartSum =  startOddCount * startOddCount;
            // the sum  of odds would be 
            // the sum of odds to the finish minus the the sum of odds to start
            // in this case 9 - 1 = 8 and if the starting number is odd we would sum it ass well
            // since 0b10 & 1 = 0 * 2 = 0 in this example is not sumed
            long oddSum = oddFinishSum - oddStartSum + ((start & 1) * start);
            // the odd count is done in the same fashion
            // 3 - 1 = 2 and we would sum one if start was odd
            long oddCount = finishOddCount - startOddCount + (start & 1);
            // now this I had to write a bit on white board but is quite simple to see
            // 1 + 3 + 5 = 9  and 2 + 4 = 6
            // if finish was even that would be 2 + 4 + 6 = 12
            // 6 = 9 - 3 that is sum of odd - count of odd is sum of even
            // if finish was even 9 + 3 = 12
            // in case you ar wondering the following is a ternary if else statement
            // you also see them in javascript
            // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator
            long evenFinishSum = (finish & 1) == 1 ? oddFinishSum - finishOddCount : oddFinishSum + finishOddCount;
            // same for the start 
            // 2 & 1 = 1 so 
            // odd start sum = 1 - 1 = 0
            long evenStartSum = (start & 1) == 1 ? oddStartSum - startOddCount : oddStartSum + startOddCount - start;
            // even sum is difference between the two
            // in this cas is 6- 0 = 6
            long evenSum = evenFinishSum - evenStartSum;
            // total sum is the sum of evens and odds
   
            long totalSum = oddSum + evenSum;
            // cound of evens is the total count minus the cound of odds
            return new Result(oddCount, totalNumCount - oddCount, totalSum);
        }


        public static void Main(){
            Console.WriteLine("Give me a Natural(including 0): ");
            // use long so you see time difference on big numbers
            long numberOne = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Give me another: ");
            long numberTwo = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
            // if numbers are equal we return 0 as in the loop
            var result = new Result(0, 0 ,0);
            if (numberOne != numberTwo){
                // get the max number between the two
                long finish = Math.Max(numberOne, numberTwo);
                // not using min, just cancel the one that was larger
                long start = numberOne + numberTwo - finish;
                // get result from function
                result  = mathPreliminaries(start, finish);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Sum - {result.sum}, Even - {result.eavenCount}, Odd -{result.oddCount}");
            // run as loop to see time difference on large numbers
            long sum = 0;
            for (long i = numberOne+1; i < numberTwo; i++)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }   
    }
}
```

You can also mix this with: sum of n = ((n^2)/2) + n/2

Comment: This answer could use more insightful observations about the code.